# psycopg2 difficuty in formatting an array of user defined types in calling postgres stored function

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using postgres 9.1 and python 2.7 with psycopg2. I have a user-defined type, as

```
CREATE TYPE RegCompT AS (short_name VARCHAR, description VARCHAR, currency CHAR(3), NumId INTEGER);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cw.create_tree( IN treespec RegCompT[] )...
```

I am trying to create an array of objects of this type in python and invoke this stored function. Here is my python code:

```
import os, sys, csv, psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions as ps2e
# -- see http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#adapting-new-python-types-to-sql-syntax
class RegDefT(object):
    def __init__(self, row): 
        self.short_name, self.desc, self.currency, self.N = row[0:4]

def adapt_RegDefT(x):
    return ps2e.AsIs("'(%s, %s, %s, %s)'" % (ps2e.adapt(x.short_name), ps2e.adapt(x.desc), ps2e.adapt(x.currency), ps2e.adapt(x.N)))  
ps2e.register_adapter( RegDefT, adapt_RegDefT )

# -- some regions
region_defs = []
region_defs.append( RegDefT( ["NA", "North America", "USD", 10] ) )
region_defs.append( RegDefT( ["EMEA", "Europe Middle-east Africa", "EUR", 11] ) )
region_defs.append( RegDefT( ["APAC", "Asia Pacific", "USD", 20] ) )

# using it
try:
    dbcon = psycopg2.connect( "dbname=lab" )
    curs = dbcon.cursor()
    qs = "select * from cw.create_tree(%s)"
    print "SQL GENERATED:", curs.mogrify( qs, [region_defs] )
    curs.execute( qs, [region_defs] )
except Exception, e:
    print "failed to execute:", qs, e
```

But what it produces works neither thru python nor thru psql:

```
SQL GENERATED: select * from cw.create_tree(ARRAY['('NA', 'North America', 'USD', 10)', '('EMEA', 'Europe Middle-east Africa', 'EUR', 11)', '('APAC', 'Asia Pacific', 'USD', 20)'])
failed to execute: select * from cw.create_tree(%s) syntax error at or near "NA"
LINE 1: select * from cw.create_tree(ARRAY['('NA', 'North America', ...
```

What I believe postgresql wants is a different formatting of the array specifier - without quoting the strings, not '( but "( and not "ARRAY[" but '{.

```
select * from cw.create_tree( '{"(NA, North America, USD, 10)", 
                                "(EMEA, Europe Middle-east Africa, EUR, 11)",
                                "(APAC, Asia Pacific, USD, 20)" }');
```

What am doing wrong at the python end? Or is it some option to be set in postgresql to accept an alternative specification for arrays? Version for psycopg2 shows as python-psycopg2-2.4.5-3.1.2.x86_64 in zypper -- is this the appropriate version?

Thanks

Comment: @Talvalin: thanks!!! Now I see that the the example on http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html had me going the wrong way.

Comment: Listing this as a duplicate per talvalin's point.